# sed not print matching group as expected

Tags: sed

What I expect is that only **letter** will be in my first group but I still get **digit**.

Here is my sed:
`echo "AAA-TTS-MAN-M4A ,abc,blurblur" |sed -r 's/(\(-?[A-Z]+)\)\(,[a-z]{2,}\)\(,.*\)/\1\/2\/3/p'`

I expect that this vents only:
`AAA-TTS-MAN ,abc,blurblur`

But instead it also show M4A which has a digit.

Please help me to understand where I am wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En 's/^([A-Z]+\b(-[A-Z]+\b)*)[^,]*((,[a-z]+)*).*/\1\3/p' file
```

Use the `-E` option so as to reduce the number of backslashes for `(`,`)` and `+` operators. Use the `-n` option to prevent implicit printing.

- The regexp is anchored to the start of the line by using the `^` operator.
- The first back reference should return the first field less any unwanted hyphenated words.

  - `[A-Z]+\b` matches one or more upper case letters ending with a word boundary.
  - `(-[A-Z]+\b)*` matches zero or more hyphenated words.
- `[^,]*` matches zero or more non comma characters (these characters will be lost).
- `(,[a-z]+)*` matches zero or more lower case character words preceded by a comma.
- `.*` matches any remaining characters to the end of the line (again lost).

N.B. Grouping and back references use parens as delimiters so back references 2 and 4 are swallowed up by back references 1 and 3 respectively.

Following the comment from the OP:

```
sed -E 's/^([A-Z]*([0-9][A-Z0-9]*)+-)+//;:a;/^[^,]*[0-9]/s/-[A-Z]*([0-9][A-Z0-9]*)+\b//;ta' file
```

The first substitution removes any words at the start of the first field. The second substitution is within a loop (since the each substitution must refer to the start of the line) and prefixed by regexp to guarantee that the substitution only effects the first field.